# Problemas al llamar a un Fragment desde un Activity

Tags: java, android-studio, activity, fragment

Mi problema es el siguiente: tengo un **`MyLocationActivity.java`** que me da la ubicación en google maps, el ejemplo que tengo para mandar a llamar a ese archivo es para llamar a un fragmento que tengo declarado en mi **`MainActivity.java`** y lo que quiero es mandar a llamar a mi segunda actividad **`MyLocationFragment.java`** (a ese archivo lo llame fragmento por que con el inicie pruebas para mostrar el fragmento, pero cambie su codigo interno a FragmentActivity (por todo el codigo contenido))

> Error: incompatible types: MyLocationFragment cannot be converted to
>   Fragment

MainActivity.java (drawable layout)

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_mylocation) {
        MyLocationFragment myLocationFragment = new MyLocationFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, myLocationFragment).commit();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el problema es que estas mezclando peras con manzanas, MyLocationFragment es un FragmentActivity por lo tanto, hereda de Activity no de Fragment.

Luego intentas usar `replace()` que sirve para remplazar `Fragments` pero en realidad estas mandandole un Activity y por eso falla.

```
if (id == R.id.nav_mylocation) {
   Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyLocationFragment.class);
   startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Tambien te recomiendo que hagas un refactor/rename y le pongas el nombre correcto a tu clase, se te puede complicar cuando la app cresca y ya no recuerdes que tu Activity se llama Fragment.

Comment: Ok, si tienes razon y ya intente eso, por eso recurri a los fragmentos, lo que pasa es que tengo un Drawable Layout y quiero que mi frame de google maps este por debajo de ese layout, por que cuando lo mando a llamar con Intent ignora al layout y se queda hasta arriba sin poder regresar

Comment: Bien, tu Drawable pertenece a un Activity y si lanzas otro Activity ya no se vera el Drawable.
Entonces deberias resolverlo con fragments como bien habias intentado, pero entonces para resolver tu problema no basta con llamarlo de una forma u otra, sino que deberas cambiar tu MyLocationFragment de ser un Activity a ser un Fragment. Y llamarlo con el replace como intentabas.

Comment: ok eso intente hacer tambien, pero por tantos cambios que he hecho no me muestra la ubicacion, si muestra el frame pero no muestra la ubicacion, pensando yo que son por permisos

Comment: Eso va mucho mas allá de la pregunta, si tenes algun otro problema con la app. podes marcar como resuelta esta pregunta y hacer otra pregunta con tus otros problemas

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el problema se encuentra en el `import` al momento de llamar `getFragmentManager()`.

Cuando uses getFragmentManager(), asegurate de que todas las clases de tus fragments (En este caso tu `MyLocationFragment`) extiendan de la clase `android.app.Fragment`.

Aunque si por casualidad estas usando `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, entonces utiliza `getSupportFragmentManager()` en su lugar.